# I have two hashmap HashMap<String,List<String>> in this format how to compare both the values are same or not with same keys

Tags: java, hashmap

```
HashMap<String,List<String>> dPlatemap

HashMap<String,List<String>> ePlatemap
```

The map contains List of values

Comment: `dPlatemap.equals(ePlatemap)` should check if two maps contain equal keys and values assigned to them. Are you having some problems while using it or did I perhaps misunderstood your question?

Comment: Keep in mind that `sets` are considered equal with the same elements without regard to order.  For `Lists`, order also matters.

Comment: what you want，you can add a simple example help other to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question "how to compare both the values are same or not with same keys" may need some clarification:

1. If you want to check if both maps have the same keys, and each key has same values and order since it's an List, you can use
   `dPlatemap.equals(ePlatemap)`
2. If you want to check if both maps have the same values, for a given key, add a small util method could help, sth. like that:

```
boolean checkEqual(Map<String, List<String>> dPlatemap, Map<String, List<String>> ePlatemap, String Key) {
    if (!dPlatemap.containsKey(key) && !ePlatemap.containsKey(key)) 
        return true;
    if (!dPlatemap.containsKey(key) || !ePlatemap.containsKey(key)) 
        return false;
    return  dPlatemap.get(key).equals(ePlatemap.get(key));
}
```

Comment: i want to check if both map has same keys and if both keys has has same value then all the keys i want as a list<String>

Comment: Then use ```dPlatemap.equals(ePlatemap)```, which also check the order of the elements in the List.